# I've got the following differential equation, how do I integrate the expression to get the answer?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

-Solve the differential equation ,with the given condition:
$${\partial z \over \partial x}+(2e^x-y){\partial z \over \partial y}=0.\ \  z=y\ \ \  at \  \ \ \ \ x=0. $$

I solve it as follows:

$${dx \over 1}={dy \over 2e^x-y}$$ then that is integrated into (which I would like for someone to explain how)

$$ye^x-e^{2x}=C$$

Comment: Hi  Bozo Vulicevic !  I am surprised by your method of solving and even more by your result. Indeed, the solution of the PDE is a function of $x$ and $y$, since the unknown in $z(x,y)$.  It is not a function $y(x)$, without leading to what we are looking for $z(x,y)=$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the PDE :
$${\partial z \over \partial x}+(2e^x-y){\partial z \over \partial y}=0.$$
according to the boundary condion $z(0,y)=y \:$ is :
$$z(x,y)=e^x y-e^{2x}+1$$
as shown below :

[image]

One can check the above solution in bringing back $z=e^x y-e^{2x}+1$ into the PDE. And it is easy to see that $z(0,y)=y$ , as required.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=1$ , letting $x(0)=0$ , we have $x=t$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=2e^x-y=2e^t-y$ , we have $y=e^t+y_0e^{-t}=e^x+y_0e^{-x}$

$\dfrac{dz}{dt}=0$ , letting $z(0)=f(y_0)$ , we have $z(x,y)=f(y_0)=f(ye^x-e^{2x})$

$z(0,y)=y$ :

$f(y-1)=y$

$f(y)=y+1$

$\therefore z(x,y)=ye^x-e^{2x}+1$

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, rewrite it as
$$
y'=2e^x-y,
$$
which is first order and linear,
$$
y'+y=2e^x,\quad\text{so}\quad D(e^x y)=2e^{2x},\quad\text{and hence}\quad e^xy=e^{2x}+C.
$$

Comment: $y$ is not the function, it's just a variable. The function is $z$.

Comment: Indeed, but the question was how to come from $dx/1=dy/(2e^x-y)$ to $e^xy-e^2x=C$ if I did not misunderstand it.

Comment: The first step was a mistake. You can't just divide both sides by $\partial z$.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was the so-called "Lagrange-Charpit equations", see [wiki on method of characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) (not dividing by $\partial z$, because that is not what there is).